# How to download a binary file that is part of a multipart SOAP response using javascript

Tags: javascript, soap, mtom

I am making a SOAP API call from my javascript code on the browser, and getting the following multi-part response. 
I need to extract the binary content that is part of this response, and save as a zip file. 
How do I do that? Are there any libraries or utilities available to do this? Any sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Response Header contains the boundary string used in the multipart content in the response body.

```
Content-Type: multipart/related;type="application/xop+xml";boundary="----=_Part_11028_1473431451.1589486493042";start="<c09b0182-f9b7-4ea0-9c8f-b22375e498d3>";start-info="text/xml"
```

Response Body is as follows:

```
------=_Part_10956_759790667.1589484354761
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=UTF-8;type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <d43bb83b-6582-42b1-ac15-5530b7fd8a32>
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><env:Header>
<wsa:Action>http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService//ErpIntegrationService/downloadESSJobExecutionDetailsResponse</wsa:Action>
</env:Header>
    <env:Body><ns0:downloadESSJobExecutionDetailsResponse >
    <ns0:DocumentTitle>ESS_L_337666</ns0:DocumentTitle><ns0:DocumentName>337666.zip</ns0:DocumentName><ns0:DocumentId xsi:nil="true"/></ns2:result></ns0:downloadESSJobExecutionDetailsResponse></env:Body></env:Envelope>
    ------=_Part_10956_759790667.1589484354761
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
    Content-ID: <135bfc6e-7557-495b-a45c-5d2be9eac890>
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[binary content here...]

------=_Part_10956_759790667.1589484354761--
```

Comment: Did u find any solution?